# vb 2008 click on specific window with coords

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

i'm using Visual Basic 2008, and my question is following:
Is here a way to make vb2008 app click on specific window with coordinates?
for example i want to click on my notepad window ( for example on next coords: 20;150 )

thanks

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Just use the `AutoIT` utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`SendInput` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using [this managed wrapper](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).